# How can I solve recurrence relation T(n)=T(√n)+O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, recurrence

When I tried solving T(n)=T(√n)+O(n) I got GP of powers and I don't know how to solve that. I want to get the exact answer not in the form of O().

Comment: Hint:  Let U(x) = T(2^(2^x))).  Then solve U(x) = U(x-1) + O(2^(2^x))